# 5 month old not eating enough

Tags: feeding, bottle-feeding

My 5-month old daughter started taking bottles of expressed breast milk about 1 month ago, since her mother needed to go back to work. Up until 5 days ago, she takes about ~24 oz per 24 hours (3 feedings of 5-6 oz during the day, and 1-2 feedings of 4-5 oz during the night).

Starting about 5 days ago, she would only take about 2-3 oz per feeding (turns her head away or refuses to suck on the nipple after that), with the last feeding of the day (~7pm) being especially bad (only take 1-2 oz from bottle, and her mother then breast feeds her after that, which she does take). The night feeding is ok, once for 5 oz.

As a result, her total intake now is only about 15-16 oz per 24 hours.

She doesn't really cry out of hunger, and does not show any other signs of distress (smiles, no cries for no reason, reasonably energetic) during the day or night.

What can be the cause? Should we be concerned?

Comment: Is she getting any other food?

Comment: @WillowRex I thought 5 month old do not eat other stuff apart from milk

Comment: @Rishi M y now daughter was eating a baby cereal at that time because her birth mum's milk was dwindling. The OP never returned, and so I hope they sorted it out with their doctor.

Comment: @WillowRex My daughter was born on 16 jan So as its only 1.5 month she is entirely on milk, BTW how long an infant can depends on milk?

I thought 7-8 months, any ways you are right OP must have sorted it out

Comment: @Rishi I hope OP did sort it out. Most babies don't start semi-solids until 7 months or so... but different countries, different doctors, different mums, different babies -- all add up to there is no 'one way'.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, seek professional/medical attention just in case. Maybe your medic can suggest other food.

Then, as asked before, check out if she is having another kind of intake.

Lack of hunger is not definitely a bad symptom, having in mind that she's energetic and doesn't cries from hunger).